# Do ORM's implement encryption?

Tags: security, orm, encryption

Typically the model for ORM's that I've used goes something like this:

Program startup: Initialize ORM db connection
While running: make/modify/delete domain objects, commit changes, rinse and repeat.
Program shutdown: commit any uncommitted changes if necessary, disconnect ORM db connection

What if someone is sniffing network traffic though (and what if the application gets used over the internet)? Are the persistent objects in any way secured? I don't recall seeing any documentation for any ORMs talking about encryption.

Comment: How is this the responsibility of the ORM? This a network-level traffic problem, and nothing to do with ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every ORM I've seen requires instructions on how to connect to the database. If it is configured to use an encrypted transport, then the data will be encrypted in transit.